# Python ImportError: No module named test_framework - I just do not get it

Tags: python

I am sorry I have to ask this question. It feels stupid, because I am sure the answer is *somewhere* and I can just not find it. All posts I read give me the feeling I did things right but obviously its not ...

I get an `ImportError: No module named test_framework` and I do really not understand why.

My folder structure is:

```
src/
 |
 -- test/
 |    |
 |    -- test_framework/
 |    |      |
 |    |      -- __init__.py
 |    |      -- device.py
 |    |
 |    -- __init__.py
 |
 -- myPackage/
     |
     -- __init__.py
     -- dbg_session.py
     -- main.py
```

In dbg_session.py I have the following line which produces the error:

```
from test.test_framework import device
```

I also tried to insert the following line before the import:

```
sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT) # pointing to src/
from test.test_framework import device
```

Also did not help:

```
import test.test_framework.device
```

the error is then:

```
ImportError: No module named test_framework.device
```

which looks to me as `test` was found but not the folder `test_framework`.

I am calling my program from `src` with something like `python.exe myPackage/main.py`

If I change the import to

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'test'))
from test_framework import device
```

it works fine but feels not right and pylint is complaining that the import cannot be resolved. My question looks like this one:
[ImportError: No module named - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587457/importerror-no-module-named-python)
but I think I got the paths right. PROJET_ROOT is a relative path, I also tried to insert the absolute path on my disk there, but that did not help. I am pretty sure that PROJET_ROOT points correctly to src, we use this at many places.

Comment: What happens if you import just `test` then print `test.__file__`? (or `sys.modules['test']`) You may well be conflicting with an other module somewhere and absolutely not importing what you're expecting.

Comment: Ahhh! Yes, of cause. Grrr. Due to some internal rules and using pytest, we need to call this folder test. But `import test`references to my python installation python27/lib/test. Thank you very much. Is there any way to tell python to use the right folder?

Comment: Insert `PROJECT_ROOT` at the start of sys.path (`sys.path.insert(0, ...)`) instead of appending: Python's import machinery traverses `sys.path` in order, and the stdlib paths are in there. Interestingly / annoyingly things can seem to work when leveraging `cwd` because *that* is automatically inserted as the *first* entry in sys.path. Incidentally when you specify `PYTHONPATH` those are prepended to the list (before cwd is prepended as well), so running with something like PYTHONPATH=$PROJECT_ROOT is an other option.

Comment: I would like to upvote you but sadly stack overflow does not allow solutions in comments ^^ Thank you very much.

Comment: I can reformat the comments as a proper answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `import` works.
You need to import `test.test_framework.device` or if you have a specific `class` e.g. `Device` you can do `from test.test_framework.device import Device`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this also did not help

Comment: What do you have in your `__init__.py` files?

Comment: They are empty.

Comment: What do you get if you call main from its folder?

Answer (score -1):

you can run the code like this.
`python -m test.test_framework.device`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40304201/5573616