# My main.py script is running in pycharm IDE but not from terminal. Why is this so?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, pycharm

When I want to run my python main.py script in the terminal it raises the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    from typeform_api import get_data  # Step 1)
  File "/Users/philipp/Documents/PycharmProjects/Wegekompass/typeform_api.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pandas as pd  # For creating a dataframe for the data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I already read the answers of those two questions, but couldn't find any solutions:

- [Import statement works on PyCharm but not from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304117/import-statement-works-on-pycharm-but-not-from-terminal)
- [Python: 'ModuleNotFoundError' when trying to import module from imported package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598292/python-modulenotfounderror-when-trying-to-import-module-from-imported-package/54613085)

This is my main.py method:

```
"""
Logic Flow of main.py:
1) Fetch Data with API
2) Preprocess the Data
3) Start topic modeling
4) Create report and include data
5) send report via e-mail to user
"""

import os
import sys
from typeform_api import get_data  # Step 1)
from preprocessing import preprocess_data  # Step 2)
from topic_modeling import create_topic_model  # Step 3)
from create_report import *  # Step 4)
from send_report import send_report  # Step 5)

if __name__ == '__main__':

# 1) Fetch Data with Typeform API:
alle_antworten_txt = get_data()[3]
projektname = get_data()[0]
projekt_id = get_data()[1]
user_email = get_data()[2]
heute_txt_short = get_data()[3][4]
heute_txt_long = get_data()[3][1:3]
heute_txt_long_joined = ". ".join(heute_txt_long)
morgen_txt_short = get_data()[3][8]
morgen_txt_long = get_data()[3][5:7]
morgen_txt_long_joined = ". ".join(morgen_txt_long)
erfolgshebel_txt_short = get_data()[3][17]
erfolgshebel_txt_long = get_data()[3][14:16]
erfolgshebel_txt_long_joined = ". ".join(erfolgshebel_txt_long)
staerken_txt = get_data()[3][12:13]
staerken_txt_joined = ". ".join(staerken_txt)
schwaechen_txt = get_data()[3][10:11]
schwaechen_txt_joined = ". ".join(schwaechen_txt)
reflexion_txt = get_data()[3][9]
etappe1_fachlich_txt = get_data()[3][18]
etappe1_kulturell_txt = get_data()[3][19]
etappe2_fachlich_txt = get_data()[3][20]
etappe2_kulturell_txt = get_data()[3][21]
etappe3_fachlich_txt = get_data()[3][22]
etappe3_kulturell_txt = get_data()[3][23]
weg_von_energie = get_data()[4][0]
hin_zu_energie = get_data()[4][1]
umsetzungsenergie = get_data()[4][2]

# 2) Preprocess and tokenize fetched Data:
alle_antworten_txt_tokens = preprocess_data(alle_antworten_txt)[1]
heute_txt_long_tokens = preprocess_data(heute_txt_long)[1]
morgen_txt_long_tokens = preprocess_data(morgen_txt_long)[1]

# 3) Start NLP analysis:
# answer_analysis = create_topic_model(alle_antworten_txt_tokens)[1]
try:
    heute_wortwolke = create_topic_model(heute_txt_long_tokens)[2]
    heute_wortwolke.to_file(os.getcwd() + "/Grafiken/Wortwolken/heute_wortwolke"+projekt_id+".png")
    morgen_wortwolke = create_topic_model(morgen_txt_long_tokens)[2]
    morgen_wortwolke.to_file(os.getcwd() + "/Grafiken/Wortwolken/morgen_wortwolke"+projekt_id+".png")

except ValueError:
    print("There is not enough word input, LDA analysis raises ValueError")
    sys.exit(0)

# 4) Create final report:
try:
    final_report = create_final_report(heute_txt_short,
                                       morgen_txt_short,
                                       erfolgshebel_txt_short,
                                       heute_txt_long_joined,
                                       morgen_txt_long_joined,
                                       erfolgshebel_txt_long_joined,
                                       staerken_txt_joined,
                                       schwaechen_txt_joined,
                                       reflexion_txt,
                                       os.getcwd() + "/Grafiken/Wortwolken/heute_wortwolke"+projekt_id+".png",
                                       os.getcwd() + "/Grafiken/Wortwolken/morgen_wortwolke"+projekt_id+".png",
                                       etappe1_fachlich_txt,
                                       etappe1_kulturell_txt,
                                       etappe2_fachlich_txt,
                                       etappe2_kulturell_txt,
                                       etappe3_fachlich_txt,
                                       etappe3_kulturell_txt,
                                       weg_von_energie,
                                       hin_zu_energie,
                                       umsetzungsenergie,
                                       projektname,
                                       projekt_id)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("There is not enough word input, wordcloud can't be computed so FileNotFoundError is raised")
    sys.exit(0)

# 5) Send final report:
try:
    send_report(final_report, user_email, projektname, projekt_id)
except NameError:
    print("variable final_report not defined due missing wordclouds")
    sys.exit(0)

# 6) Check if program reached its end:
print("If this gets print, the report was send successfully.")
```

This is the structure of my project folder:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── Error-Handling.md
├── Grafiken
│   ├── 1Etappe_Card-min.png
│   ├── 2Etappe_Card-min.png
│   ├── 3Etappe_Card-min.png
│   ├── AD_Logo-min.png
│   ├── Dynamik_Abflug-min.png
│   ├── Dynamik_Anflug-min.png
│   ├── Dynamik_Hoehenflug-min.png
│   ├── Dynamik_Parabelflug-min.png
│   ├── Dynamik_Sinkflug-min.png
│   ├── Dynamik_Steigflug-min.png
│   ├── Dynamik_Talflug-min.png
│   ├── Dynamik_Tiefflug-min.png
│   ├── Entwicklung_Card-min.png
│   ├── Erfolgshebel_Card-min.png
│   ├── Framework_Abflug-min.png
│   ├── Framework_Anflug-min.png
│   ├── Framework_Hoehenflug-min.png
│   ├── Framework_Parabelflug-min.png
│   ├── Framework_Sinkflug-min.png
│   ├── Framework_Steigflug-min.png
│   ├── Framework_Talflug-min.png
│   ├── Framework_Tiefflug-min.png
│   ├── Heute_Card-min.png
│   ├── Morgen_Card-min.png
│   ├── Reflexion_Card-min.png
│   ├── Strength_Card-min.png
│   ├── Weakness_Card-min.png
│   ├── Wegekompass_Hero-min.png
│   └── Wortwolken
├── PDF_Reports
├── README.md
├── __pycache__
│   ├── config.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── create_report.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── main.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── preprocessing.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── send_report.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── topic_modeling.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── typeform_api.cpython-38.pyc
├── config.py
├── create_report.py
├── html_files
│   └── E_Mail_Template.html
├── main.py
├── preprocessing.py
├── requirements.txt
├── send_report.py
├── topic_modeling.py
├── typeform_api.py
└── venv
    ├── (...)
```

As I said - the main.py script runs in pycharm IDE, but not from the terminal.

How can I run my script from the terminal?

Comment: install pandas
```pip install pandas``` or ```pip3 install pandas```

Comment: You have to activate the venv in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html),
did you activate it before running your script?

For Linux/Mac you can do the following:

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

For windows you should use:

```
source venv/Scripts/activate
```

after activating the virtual environment, you can install packages with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```