# Python Code works in PyCharm on Mac but not on FreeBSD Jail

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, filepath

I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553668/script-running-in-pycharm-but-not-from-the-command-line), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304117/import-statement-works-on-pycharm-but-not-from-terminal) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348711/python-works-in-pycharm-but-not-from-terminal) but still not sure how to fix it.

I am doing my dev work on my `Mac` using `PyCharm` and everything works and imports.

When I take this `project directory` to `FreeBSD jail`. It `fails to load` internal directory code. and gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project/src/my_script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.auth import MyClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I am trying to execute the file `my_script.py` which imports `src.auth.py`

My Directory structure looks like this:

```
project
  /src
   __init__.py   
   my_script.py
   auth.py
__init__.py
.env
```

both `__init.py__` are empty files. Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Pycharm always sets the Python path to the project's base directory, which is why you need to import your code with the actual path to the files, e.g. `from src. ...`. This is not the default behavior for other programs/ways to run Python. Try removing `src.` from all your import statements.

Comment: thanks. So if I need to import the `auth.py`.  What's the best way to import this? @jfaccioni

Comment: Simply writing `from auth import ...` should suffice (assuming the folder structure you posted above).

Comment: when I do from `from auth import ...` pycharm gives error: `Unresolved reference 'auth'

Comment: Yes because as I said, PyCharm by default sets the working directory to your project root (the folder called `project`), not to folder `src`, where your code actually lies. In PyCharm, you need to change the working directory to `/path/to/your/project/src` (in the execution bar top right corner > "Edit Configurations..."), and mark the folder `src` as the source code folder (right click it on the project viewer > "Mark Directory as").